# spring mvc 4 Return JSON in an infinite loop

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

entity :

```
class A{
   private int id;
   @oneToMany(mappedBy = "a")
   private List<B> bList;
}
class B{
   private int id;
   @ManToOne
   private A a;
}
```

repository :

```
interfase BRepository{ 
   @Query("select b from B b where b.a.id = ?1")
   public List<B> getB(String id);
}
```

controller :

```
private BRepository b;
@RequestMapping("/b")
public Object getB(){
     return b.getB(1);
}
```

return JSON in an infinite loop .

Use the @JsonBackReference annotation on the class A, normal results :

```
   class A{
   private int id;
   @oneToMany(mappedBy = "a")
   @JsonBackReference  //this property is ignored
   private List<B> bList;
}
```

But when you query a class, the returned results not bList (using @JsonBackference), what can I do to return the bList properties?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest **not to use** circular references between your objects for [the following reasons](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/12030).

This generate a lot of issues and JSON generation is one of them.

> •Circular class references create high coupling; both classes must be recompiled every time either of them is changed.
>
> •Circular assembly references prevent static linking, because B depends on A but A cannot be assembled until B is complete.
>
> •Circular object references can crash naïve recursive algorithms (such as serializers, visitors and pretty-printers) with stack overflows. The more advanced algorithms will have cycle detection and will merely fail with a more descriptive exception/error message.
>
> •Circular object references also make dependency injection impossible, significantly reducing the testability of your system.
>
> •Objects with a very large number of circular references are often God Objects. Even if they are not, they have a tendency to lead to Spaghetti Code.
>
> •Circular entity references (especially in databases, but also in domain models) prevent the use of non-nullability constraints, which may eventually lead to data corruption or at least inconsistency.
>
> •Circular references in general are simply confusing and drastically increase the cognitive load when attempting to understand how a program functions.